# Price number format for osclass with comma decimal point

Tags: php, jquery

Hi guys ho do i format this to a number field where you can use only number separated with comma and decimal point (This is for a price field) ex 150,850.00

And how to let appears the comma and decimal point auto generated?

```
<input 
  placeholder="<?php osc_esc_html(_e('Price', 'ctg_housing')) ; ?> 
  <?php osc_esc_html(_e('Min', 'ctg_housing')) ; ?>" 
  type="text" id="priceMin" name="sPriceMin" 
  value="<?php echo osc_esc_html(osc_search_price_min()); ?>" 
  onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#priceMin').keyup(function(event){
        var $elm = $(this);
        var value = $elm.val();
        var result = value.replace(/[^0-9\.\,]+/g, "");
        $elm.val(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: I have testet it, so it should - have you included jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the JS code that would add `comma` to the numbers and also a code that would remove comma from the numbers. It's a function that accepts number, so you can use it anywhere:

```js
function getNumberWithCommas(yourNumber) {
  var n = yourNumber.toString().split(".");
  n[0] = n[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  return n.join(".");
}
var numberWithComma = getNumberWithCommas(1136324);
console.log(numberWithComma);

numberWithComma = numberWithComma.replace(/\,/g, '');
console.log(parseInt(numberWithComma));
```